# cannot import name 'fmeasure_acc' from 'talos.metrics.keras_metrics'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, artificial-intelligence, talos

```
import talos as ta
```

is ok in Anaconda on Windows 10, but if I need to import some commands did not recognize talos

```
import talos as ta
import wrangle as wr
from talos.metrics.keras_metrics import fmeasure_acc
from talos import live
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'fmeasure_acc' from
>   'talos.metrics.keras_metrics'
>   (C:\Users\Libardo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\talos\metrics\keras_metrics.py)

Answer (score 0):

From the Github repo: https://github.com/autonomio/talos/blob/master/talos/metrics/keras_metrics.py.

The function `fmeasure_acc` does not exist.